# Query strings showing in SERPs

Tags: url, search-results, hacking, query-string

One of our sites got hacked, we believe we have resolved this issue, but when doing a `site:example.com` in Google, we are still seeing query strings like: `example.com/?black-book-subtitles`.

- Could it be possible that the site is still hacked?
- Is there a way to remove these URLs from the search engines?

Comment: The question is, How long has it been?? It takes a long time for Google to refetch the pages and update the index depending upon the freshness and relative importance of the site. You can use Fetch as Google in Search Console, however this still takes a couple of days and you would have to enter one page at a time with limitations. Not advisable in your case except to test.